Using setCustomValidity stops input from validating
I'm wanting to set a custom validation message when my input does not meet the required regex pattern.
I know that we can use the setCustomValidity() function built into an input to do this, however upon adding this I am finding that checkValidity now never resolves as true on the input.
I understand that setting a custom validation message means the input will always be considered invalid until the message is unset, and in essence will override the checkValidity... So it seems like a bit of a catch 22. If I want to set a custom validation message, I can't use checkValidity?
const cvvReg = /\b\d{3}\b/;

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const input = e.target;
    const isValid = input.checkValidity();
    setInputValid(isValid);
    input.setCustomValidity(isValid ? "" : "custom validation message");
  };

...

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={formStyle}>
      <input
        type="text"
        pattern={cvvReg.source}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

How can I get this to work?
Link to codesandbox

Why not just use the regex, directly, in handleChange? You don't need to extract the source to set the pattern to validate the element to get the validity, just see if it matches the target's value.

You probably want ^\d{1,3}$

@jonrsharpe do you mean me changing isValid to equal something like new RegExp(input.pattern).test(input.value);?

No, you already have the RegExp - cvvReg. Why extract the source to set the pattern of the element then pull the pattern back out of the element to create a new RegExp with the same pattern?!
